# Ingesting Landsat8 Collection 1 Level 1 dataset

Tags: open-data-cube

I am done with indexing, now trying to ingest. I couldn't find any examples for the ingest config for landsat8 collection 1 level 1, does anybody have any samples out there?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't ingest!

While we do have documentation on ingesting data, it's not something that we do at Digital Earth Australia, we just index data off S3 or a file system.

If you really want to ingest, [there are some examples here](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config/tree/master/agdcv2-ingest).